# Why the application doesn't wait the answer of the user?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to create an endpoint and later a proxy in WCF, in a xamarin.adroid application. I have this code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setEndPointAddress();

    setProxy();
}




private void setEndPointAddress()
{
    try
    {
        string myAddress = GestorConfiguracion.getDireccionServicio();
        _endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress(myAddress);
    }
    catch(UriFormatException)
    {
        string myTitle = "My title";
        string miStrMessage = "My error message.";
        ShowAlert(myTitle, miStrMessage);
    }
}




private void setProxy()
{
    if(_endPointAddress != null)
    {
        _proxy = new MyProxy(_binding, _endPointAddress);
    }
}




public void ShowAlert(string paramTitle, string paramMessage)
{
    Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.SetTitle(paramTitle);
    alert.SetMessage(paramMessage);
    alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) => {

        //Code to be run after answer of the user
    });

    //run the alert in UI thread to display in the screen
    RunOnUiThread(() => {
        alert.Show();
    });
}
```

The problem is that the code on the OnCreate method runs until the end before showing the message to the user. I mean, that if I set a breakpoint in the setProxy() line in the OnCreate method, the message is not shown in the android emulator, I have to continue the execution until the end of the OnCreate method, then is when the message is shown.

The method that show the alert doesn't seem to be async or another kind that makes me to think that I should wait him.

In fact, there is no problem if I let the code run until the end, but I would like to know how it works in this way to learn about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider moving those calls from OnCreate() to OnStart() or OnResume() as the Activity is not yet created at the point you are attempting to show the Dialog.  The screen will not start drawing anything until after the OnCreate() has returned.

However, even if you move that code, the primary issue is that AlertDialog is not a modal dialog box as Android doesn't want you blocking the UI thread.